# Is there a way to force sync on Monero GUI?

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-gui, synchronization, network

I'm using the Monero GUI to download the Monero blockchain; but most of the time, after I open the GUI and start daemon, the "network status" at the lower left bit shows only the "connected" text. Ocassionally, it will shows it's syncing and how many blocks there are left; but I don't know what actually triggers it. Sometimes, even though the GUI doesn't show it, the daemon appears to be syncing as I witness the blockchain size rising.

At any rate, I'd like to be able to know **and** see that the daemon is syncing and not just running on the background doing nothing. Is there a way to do that on the GUI?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a bug. Should you not have an answer within the next couple of days, could you [fill out an issue](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/issues)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the *Settings* tab you can click the *Show Status* box.  If you want to leave this open, it will intermittently post the daemon status(I am not sure how often it updates though), or if you prefer, you can type a few commands to activate info manually(the command box is to the right of the Close box; this is your CLI interface for the GUI).

Commands to see status of daemon: **status** or **sync_info**

You can also type **help** to see the rest of the commands and what they do.

Comment: Oh, so that's how you update the status messages. I was confused about which message to look at on the status window before. Thanks.

It indeed seems the sync-display on the lower left of the GUI does not match the actual status of the daemon (for example, now it's stuck at "87118 blocks left"; but the download completion ratio in status messages appear to gradually increase). I suppose I should report it as a bug.